# How to connect arduino uno to Azure IoT Central

Tags: azure-iot-central

We want to connect Arduino uno to Microsoft Azure IoT Central. Is there any Step by Step guide or demo?

best regards
Ingo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Arduino Uno code sample for IoT Central on [Github](https://github.com/firedog1024/arduino-uno-wifi-iotc). There are quite a few other code examples in [IoT Central's Github repository](https://github.com/Azure/iot-central-firmware) as well.